# How to make a PictureBox always stay on the bottom?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to make the tangram game on winform. I have to add a shape on top of the desired shape to be created. But when I do this, the shape I drag is at the bottom.
How can I solve this. How can I make sure that the target shape always stays on the bottom?
Thanks.

```
        Big1Triangle135 big1Triangle135 = new Big1Triangle135();
        Big2Triangle45 big2Triangle45 = new Big2Triangle45();
        Small1Triangle225 small1Triangle225 = new Small1Triangle225();
        Small2Triangle315 small1Triangle315 = new Small2Triangle315();
        Square45 square45 = new Square45();
        MiddleTriangle90 middleTriangle90 = new MiddleTriangle90();
        ParallelSquare45 parallelSquare45 = new ParallelSquare45();
        Level level = new Level();//Target
        
        mainForm.Controls.Add(level);//Target
        mainForm.Controls.Add(big1Triangle135);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(big2Triangle45);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(small1Triangle225);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(small1Triangle315);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(square45);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(middleTriangle90);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(parallelSquare45);
```

[image]

This problem disappears when I first add the normally partitioned shapes to the form. But the same problem arises when I change the angle of the shape. As follows.

```
        Big1Triangle135 big1Triangle135 = new Big1Triangle135();
        Big2Triangle45 big2Triangle45 = new Big2Triangle45();
        Small1Triangle225 small1Triangle225 = new Small1Triangle225();
        Small2Triangle315 small1Triangle315 = new Small2Triangle315();
        Square45 square45 = new Square45();
        MiddleTriangle90 middleTriangle90 = new MiddleTriangle90();
        ParallelSquare45 parallelSquare45 = new ParallelSquare45();
        Level level = new Level();//Target
        
        mainForm.Controls.Add(big1Triangle135);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(big2Triangle45);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(small1Triangle225);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(small1Triangle315);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(square45);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(middleTriangle90);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(parallelSquare45);
        mainForm.Controls.Add(level);//Target
```

Comment: What is the target shape? A control or a drawn shape? You could make it a BackgroundImage. For controls you can use SendToBack or BringToFront to change the z-order..

Comment: A custom drawn picturebox.

Comment: Try `level.SendToBack();`

Comment: you can also add a BringToFront in the MouseDown of the dragable pieces, ie when the dragging starts to always have the piece the user drag on top of all others..

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. Thanks.